# Processing function is not working. It says 'Syntax Error - Missing name or ; near ‘int minimax(’?'

Tags: java, processing, minimax

i am now trying checkers......And the function definition itself is showing a problem.

I tried a bunch of stuff but nothing fixes that annoying underlined piece of code.

```
int minimax(String[][] arr, int alpha, int beta, int depth, Boolean isMaximising){ 
  String win = checkWin(arr);
  if (win != "") {
    switch(win) {
    case "b":
      return 1;
      break;
    case "w":
      return -1;
      break;
    case "Tie":
      return 0;
      break;
    }
  } else if (depth == 0) {
    return 1;
  }
  int bestScore;
  if (isMaximising == true) {
    bestScore = -3000;
    for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
        if ((arr[i][j] == "bp") || (arr[i][j] == "bk")) {
          ArrayList<int[]> t =  getLegalMoves(arr, i, j, arr[i][j]);
          for (int m = 0; m< t.size()-1; m++) {
            int[] t1 = new int[3];
            int[] t2 = new int[3];
            t1 = t.get(m);
            t2 = t.get(t.size()-1);
            if (t2[2] == 0) {
              if ( t1[2] == 0) {
                if (t1[0] == 0) {
                  arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j][0]+"k";
                  arr[i][j] = "";
                }
                int score = minimax(arr, alpha, beta, depth -1, false);
                arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]][0]+"p";
                arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
                score = max(score, bestScore);
                alpha = max(score, alpha);
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                  break;
                }
              } else {
                if (t1[0] == 0) {
                  arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j][0]+"k";
                  arr[i][j] = "";
                }
                String temp = arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2];
                arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = "";
                int score = minimax(arr, alpha, beta, depth-1, false);
                arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]][0]+"p";
                arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
                arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = temp;
                score = max(score, bestScore);
                alpha = max(score, alpha);
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    bestScore = 3000;
    for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
        if ((arr[i][j] == "wp") || (arr[i][j] == "wk")) {
          ArrayList<int[]> t =  getLegalMoves(arr, i, j, arr[i][j]);
          for (int m = 0; m< t.size()-1; m++) {
            int[] t1 = new int[3];
            int[] t2 = new int[3];
            t1 = t.get(m);
            t2 = t.get(t.size()-1);
            if (t2[2] == 0) {
              if ( t1[2] == 0) {
                if (t1[0] == 0) {
                  arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j][0]+"k";
                  arr[i][j] = "";
                }
                int score = minimax(arr, alpha, beta, depth-1, true);
                arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]][0]+"p";
                arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
                score = min(score, bestScore);
                beta = min(score, alpha);
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                  break;
                }
              } else {
                if (t1[0] == 0) {
                  arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j][0]+"k";
                  arr[i][j] = "";
                }
                String temp = arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2];
                arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = "";
                int score = minimax(arr, -3000, 3000, 6, true);
                arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]][0]+"p";
                arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
                arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = temp;
                score = min(score, bestScore);
                beta = min(score, alpha);
                if (beta <= alpha) {
                  break;
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return bestScore;
}
```

Apparently something is missing in the first line.

```
Syntax Error - Missing name or ; near ‘int minimax(’?
```

this is the error it is showing.

**Edit**

FILE: checkers:

```
float w= 600;
float h= 600;
int scl = 8;
String[][] board = new String[scl][scl];
Boolean selectMode = false;
ArrayList<int[]> l;


void mousePressed() {
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if (mouseX >= w/scl*j+50 & mouseX < w/scl*j+50 + w/scl) {
        if (mouseY >= h/scl*i+100 & mouseY < h/scl*i+100 + h/scl) {
          if (board[i][j] == "bp") {
            selectMode = true;
            l = getLegalMoves(board, i, j, board[i][j]);
            int[] temp = new int[3];
            temp = l.get(l.size()-1);
            if (temp[2] == 1) {
              selectMode = false;
            }
          } else if (board[i][j] == "") {
            if (selectMode == true) {
              for (int m = 0; m< l.size()-1; m++) {
                int[] temp = new int[3];
                temp = l.get(m);
                int[] temp1 = new int[3];
                temp1 = l.get(l.size()-1);
                if ((i == temp[0]) & (j == temp[1])) {
                  if (board[i][j].indexOf('p') != -1) {
                    if (temp[2] == 0) {
                      board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                      board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                      selectMode = false;
                    } else {
                      if (i > temp1[0]) {
                        if ( j > temp1[1]) {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]+1][temp1[1]+1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        } else {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]+1][temp1[1]-1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        }
                      } else {
                        if ( j > temp1[1]) {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]-1][temp1[1]+1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        } else {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]-1][temp1[1]-1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  } else {
                    if (temp[2] == 0) {
                      board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                      board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                      selectMode = false;
                    } else {
                      if (i > temp1[0]) {
                        if ( j > temp1[1]) {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]+1][temp1[1]+1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        } else {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]+1][temp1[1]-1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        }
                      } else {
                        if ( j > temp1[1]) {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]-1][temp1[1]+1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        } else {
                          board[i][j] = board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]];
                          board[temp1[0]][temp1[1]] = "";
                          board[temp1[0]-1][temp1[1]-1] = "";
                          selectMode = false;
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
              playMove(board);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

FILE:checkForWin

```
String checkWin(String[][] arr) {
  String winner = "";
  int cB = 0;
  int cW = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if ((arr[i][j] == "bp") || (arr[i][j] == "bk")){
        cB++;
      }
      if ((arr[i][j] == "wp") || (arr[i][j] == "wk")){
        cW++;
      }
    }
  }
  if (cB == cW) {
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] != "") {
          x++;
        }
      }
    }
    if (x*2 == cB) {
      winner = "Tie";
    }
  } else {
    if (cB == 0) {
      winner = "b";
    } else if (cW == 0) {
      winner = "w";
    }
  }
  return winner;
}
```

FILE: minimaxAlgorithm

first function is already there in the beginning

second function

```
void playMove(String[][] arr) {
  int bestScore = 3000;
  int[] bestMove = new int[5];
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if ((arr[i][j] == "wp") || (arr[i][j] == "wk")) {
        ArrayList<int[]> t =  getLegalMoves(arr, i, j, arr[i][j]);
        for (int m = 0; m< t.size()-1; m++) {
          int[] t1 = new int[3];
          int[] t2 = new int[3];
          t1 = t.get(m);
          t2 = t.get(t.size()-1);
          if (t2[2] == 0) {
            if ( t1[2] == 0) {
              if (t1[0] == 0) {
                arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j][0]+"k";
                arr[i][j] = "";
              }
              int score = 0;// minimax to be called
              arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]][0]+"p";
              arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
              if (score < bestScore) {
                score = bestScore;
                bestMove[0] = i;
                bestMove[1] = j;
                bestMove[2] = t1[0];
                bestMove[3] = t1[1];
                bestMove[4] = 0;
              }
            } else {
              arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = arr[i][j];
              arr[i][j] = "";
              String temp = arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2];
              arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = "";
              int score = minimax(arr, alpha, beta, depth-1, true);
              arr[i][j] = arr[t1[0]][t1[1]];
              arr[t1[0]][t1[1]] = "";
              arr[i+(t1[0]-i)/2][j+ (t1[1]-j)/2] = temp;
              if (score < bestScore) {
                score = bestScore;
                bestMove[0] = i;
                bestMove[1] = j;
                bestMove[2] = t1[0];
                bestMove[3] = t1[1];
                bestMove[4] = 1;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

FILE: drawing:

```
void draw() {
  background(155, 155, 155);
  strokeWeight(1);
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if ((i+j) % 2 == 0) {
        fill(210, 210, 210);
      } else {
        fill(181, 141, 110);
      }
      rect(w/scl*j+50, h/scl*i+100, w/scl, h/scl);
      ellipseMode(CENTER);
      if ( board[i][j] == "bp" ) {
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(1);
      } else if ( board[i][j] == "wp" ) {
        fill(255);
        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(1);
      }else if(board[i][j] == "bk"){
        fill(0);
        stroke(255);
        strokeWeight(4);
      } else if ( board[i][j] == "wk" ) {
        fill(255);
        stroke(0);
        strokeWeight(4);
      if ( board[i][j] != "" ) {
        ellipse(w/scl*j+(w/(2*scl)+50), h/scl*i+(h/(2*scl)+100), w/(2*scl), h/(2*scl));
      }
    }
  }
  if (selectMode == true) {
    for (int j = 0; j< l.size()-1; j++) {
      int[] temp = new int[3];
      temp = l.get(j);
      fill(256/2);
      ellipse(w/scl*temp[1]+(w/(2*scl)+50), h/scl*temp[0]+(h/(2*scl)+100), w/(2*scl), h/(2*scl));
    }
  }
}
```

FILE: settingUp:

```
void setup() {
  size(700, 800);
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if (i == 0) {
        if (j % 2 == 1) {
          board[i][j] = "wp";
        } else {
          board[i][j] = "";
        }
      } else if (i == 1) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          board[i][j] = "wp";
        } else {
          board[i][j] = "";
        }
      } else if (i == 6) {
        if (j % 2 == 1) {
          board[i][j] = "bp";
        } else {
          board[i][j] = "";
        }
      } else if (i == 7) {
        if (j % 2 == 0) {
          board[i][j] = "bp";
        } else {
          board[i][j] = "";
        }
      } else {
        board[i][j] = "";
        board[5][2] = "wp";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

finally,
FILE: moves:

```
ArrayList<int[]> getLegalMoves(String[][] arr, int indexI, int indexJ, String piece) {
  ArrayList<int[]> temp =  getAllowedMoves(arr, indexI, indexJ, 0);
  int forces = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i< scl; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j< scl; j++) {
      if (arr[i][j] == piece) {
        ArrayList<int[]> t =  getAllowedMoves(arr, i, j, 0);
        for (int m = 0; m< t.size()-1; m++) {
          int[] t1 = new int[3];
          t1 = t.get(m);
          if (t1[2] == 1) {
            forces++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Boolean flag = true;
  if (forces != 0) {
    for (int m = 0; m< temp.size()-1; m++) {
      int[] t2 = new int[3];
      t2 = temp.get(m);
      if (t2[2] == 1) {
        flag = false;
      }
    }
  } else {
    flag = false;
  }
  if (flag != true) {
    return getAllowedMoves(arr, indexI, indexJ, 0);
  } else {
    return getAllowedMoves(arr, indexI, indexJ, 1);
  }
}


ArrayList<int[]> getAllowedMoves(String[][] arr, int indexI, int indexJ, int x) {
  ArrayList<int[]> border = new ArrayList<int[]>(2);
  if (arr[indexI][indexJ] != "") {
    if (arr[indexI][indexJ] == "bp") {
      if (indexI > 0) {
        if (indexJ > 0) {
          if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "")) {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ-1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "wk")){
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ-2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ-2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (indexJ < 7) {
          if (arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "") {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ+1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "wk")) {
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ+2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ+2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (arr[indexI][indexJ] == "wp") {
      if (indexI < 7) {
        if (indexJ < 7) {
          if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "")) {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI+1;
            temp[1] = indexJ+1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "bp") || (arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "bk")) {
              if (arr[indexI+2][indexJ+2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI+2;
                temp[1] = indexJ+2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (indexJ > 0) {
          if (arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "") {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI+1;
            temp[1] = indexJ-1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "bp") || (arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "bk")) {
              if (arr[indexI+2][indexJ-2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI+2;
                temp[1] = indexJ-2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    ///kings
    if (arr[indexI][indexJ] == "bk") {
      if (indexI > 0) {
        if (indexJ > 0) {
          if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "")) {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ-1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "wk")){
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ-2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ-2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (indexJ < 7) {
          if (arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "") {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ+1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "wk")) {
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ+2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ+2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "")) {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI+1;
            temp[1] = indexJ-1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "wk")){
              if (arr[indexI+2][indexJ-2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI+2;
                temp[1] = indexJ-2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (indexJ < 7) {
          if (arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "") {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI+1;
            temp[1] = indexJ+1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "wp") || (arr[indexI+1][indexJ+1] == "wk")) {
              if (arr[indexI+2][indexJ+2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI+2;
                temp[1] = indexJ+2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (arr[indexI][indexJ] == "wk") {
      if (indexI < 7) {
        if (indexJ < 7) {
          if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "")) {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ+1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "bp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ+1] == "bk")) {
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ+2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ+2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
        if (indexJ > 0) {
          if (arr[indexI+1][indexJ-1] == "") {
            int [] temp = new int[3];
            temp[0] = indexI-1;
            temp[1] = indexJ-1;
            temp[2] = 0;
            border.add(temp);
          } else {
            if ((arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "bp") || (arr[indexI-1][indexJ-1] == "bk")) {
              if (arr[indexI-2][indexJ-2] == "") {
                int [] temp = new int[3];
                temp[0] = indexI-2;
                temp[1] = indexJ-2;
                temp[2] = 1;
                border.add(temp);
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  int [] temp1 = new int[3];
  temp1[0] = indexI;
  temp1[1] = indexJ;
  temp1[2] = x;
  border.add(temp1);
  Boolean flag = false;
  for (int i = 0; i<border.size()-1; i++) {
    int[] temp = new int[3];
    temp = border.get(i);
    if (temp[2] == 1) {
      flag = true;
    }
  }
  if (flag == true) {
    for (int i = 0; i<border.size()-1; i++) {
      int[] temp = new int[3];
      temp = border.get(i);
      if (temp[2] == 0) {
        border.remove(i);
      }
    }
  }
  return border;
}
```

forgive me for my terrible lack of organisation...

Comment: Likely missing a `;` right before this function.

Comment: no this is a separate tab

Comment: The function itself is not the problem. The problem is a code before this function. Probably the end of another tab's code.

Comment: What line do you get the error at? @Rabbid76 got it correctly, the error message tells you exactly what is wrong...

Comment: I figured out the problem and now there is another problem

Comment: In the checkers file, it shows I have made mistake by confusing active and static modes

Comment: Open a new question if you have a new problem. And PLEASE at least try to bebug yourself before posting on SO.

Comment: Sorry thanks for the suggestion..not very good at debugging..tried to a certain extent but I ma terrible at it

Comment: It is the most valuable skill. And when the error basically says what is wrong, then you should be able to find it. If you can't then I suggest you start with some easier programs to learn first